# How to overlay images without using postion:absolute?

Tags: css

I'm looking for the proper CSS method to overlay div of images on top of another div of images (not background image) without using `position:absolute`. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why can't you use `position:absolute`?

Comment: `position: absolute` combined with `position: relative` in a parent is a very good way to overlap two objects while preserving layout for the overall page.  It creates a self-contained container that can be layed out with normal HTML box model, but inside the container, you use position for creating overlap.

Comment: You really need to explain why you're trying to avoid `position: absolute` because it's probably the best solution and there are probably ways to solve whatever you're worried about with it.

Comment: it's true that 'position:absolute' is the easiest, but it won't save me when dealing responsive design

Comment: I just wanted to second this. There are many situations where `position: absolute`, while easy, can create problems because it removes the element from consideration when laying out the document. So, the parent will not expand to fit the absolutely positioned child, potentially cutting off content.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/HUUQ6/2/

You can overlay/overlap elements on top of one another using a negative margin. 
Example:

```
#b{
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

This will move the element `b` to the left 10px, overlaying whatever is to the left of it (assuming this is a display:block type element, not an inline, like a span).

Comment: 90% of the time, negative margins are a bad idea.  Some browsers have bugs with them and they don't change the "laid out space" that is reserved for the original object.  I know the OP asked for ideas, but I'd recommend they use `position: absolute;` over negative margins.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree, but "without using position:absolute" is the essential part of the question.

Comment: I was responding for the benefit of the OP.  I don't think there is a better choice than absolute positioning for overlapping objects.  It would help if they explained why they are trying to avoid absolute positioning.  I suspect they don't understand how to use `position:relative ` on the parent.

Comment: I'm aware of this as well, and used % instead of px with position:relative to achieve a faux absolute positioning. Not ideal, but only older browsers will not support, which I couldn't care less. I'm just hoping that someone may have something else to share.

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute` isn't "improper" - it's part of the CSS spec! There isn't another way to put elements over other elements, unless you faff about with `position: relative` or maybe some `float` properties.

`position: absolute` is the easiest way to do it. What makes you think it's a bad idea?

---

The only other solution is to use an image inside a div with a background, like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

Then give the div a `background-image`:

```
div
{
    background: url(/images/foo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

However, for multiple images I'd definitely stick to `position: absolute`.

There's a *very* glitchy demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh6r8/1/) demonstrating the effect.

Comment: as mentioned on original post, cannot deal with background within div, and agree with position:absolute is easiest, but not ideal for responsive design

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to layer 2 images and center the second image.

**NOTE: "Position: absolute" in "image2" is only used so the images can overlap. It will still center your image responsively / without needing to use "left: " or "right: " or margin, and is independent of the image size.**

HTML:

```
<div class="page-container">

    <div class="images-container">
        <img class="image1" src="YOURIMAGEURLHERE" />

        <div class="image2container">
            <img class="image2" src="SECONDIMAGEURLGOESHERE" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
  

.images-container {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;     
}
      
.image1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    //if you want to blur the outer image
    //transform: scale(1.1); 
    //filter: blur(20px);
    //-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.image2container {
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

.image2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
}


.page-container{ 

}
```

SCSS (if you prefer it, which I do - makes it much easier to copy styles from 1 file to another)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.page-container {
    .images-container{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        .image1 {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            //if you want to blur the outer image
            //transform: scale(1.1); 
            //filter: blur(20px);
            //-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
          }
        .image2container {
            display: flex; 
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            .image2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```